# Install setuptools options.extras_require with pipenv

Tags: python, setuptools, pipenv

When I use `pipenv` to set up a venv for my project, it doesn't install any of the development and test dependencies from the `setuptools` `setup.cfg` 's `options.extras_require` clause, so tools like `pytest` and `pyhamcrest` aren't available within `pipenv shell`.

My `Pipfile` `[packages]` directive was created with `pipenv install -e .` and contains:

```
[packages]
my-package = {editable = true, path = "."}
```

The corresponding project's `setup.cfg` has

```
[options.extras_require]
test =
    pytest
    pytest-cov
    pyhamcrest
debug =
    ipython
    ipdb
```

But `pipenv install`, `pipenv sync --dev`, etc seem to ignore this.

Answer (score 2):

`pipenv` has the [not-very-documented](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) `extras` option available for `packages` directives. This specifies a list of `options.extras_require` package sets to install. E.g. for the above, I might have

```
my-package = {editable = true, extras = ["debug", "test"], path = "."}
```

This can be autogenerated by `pipenv` with the `pkgname[extras...]` syntax for `pipenv install`:

```
pipenv install -e '.[debug,test]'
```